# Finding a site by tag

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question on the topic X, which probably uses the tags T1 and T2.

I am not sure if the proper forum is XA or XB, so, is there a way I can get which forums are associated to a tag?

Comment: Be careful as tags may have different meanings on different sites. Apple on Stack Overflow and Seasoned Advice will get you rather different things.

Comment: Good advice. Although my tags are quite unique.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the Filtered Questions for this, by finding all existing questions, on all sites, with a specific tag:

1. Go to https://stackexchange.com/
2. Go to [Filtered Questions](https://stackexchange.com/filters)
3. Click "New Filter"
4. Choose "Just questions tagged with...":

   > [image]
5. Make sure that under "on..." the option "All Sites" is selected
6. Click the Preview button

That's it, now you can see list of questions, cross network, with that tag, and based on it you can decide which is the best for your own question.

Answer (score 3):

You can't search all sites for a specific tag only, you can though use the general cross-site search page, where you can search for a term or a tag name. It will return all posts containing that word. It will give an idea on an appropriate site to post on, but be careful to read the help center before you actually post there. Also, a tag doesn't always mean the same thing on another site.

You can find the search page [here](https://stackexchange.com/search).

It will find you the tags too, when you search for example on ['Facebook'](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=Facebook).